# Get permutations of lists using python

Tags: python, list, loops, combinations, permutation

Let's assume I have list a:

```
a = [0, 0, [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
```

where a can be of any length, and its constituents can be of any length and I want to generate a new list that can be any combination of the values such that for the given example I would return:

```
b = [[0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,1],
     [0,0,0,2], 
     [0,0,1,0],
     [0,0,1,1],
     [0,0,1,2]]
```

I think it's just a matter of looping, but I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [0, 0, [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
>>> a2 = [x if isinstance(x, list) else [x] for x in a]
>>> #  = [[0], [0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
>>> list(itertools.product(*a2))
[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 2)]
```

Comment: is the # comment intentional?

Comment: @MightyPork, Yes, it is. I want to tell that elements should be sequences (not a int).